# element & fetch in cakephp2

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

What's the difference between 'fetch' and 'element' in cakephp2? I have this code

```
 echo $this->fetch('meta');
```

in the default.ctp and have no clue why it's there. Can't I just use $this->element('meta') and will have to create meta.ctp in the elements folder.

Also this code

```
echo $this->fetch('content');
```

is in the content portion. Can someone explain this please? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fetch` will get the data and render it over there.

```
 echo $this->fetch('meta');
```

Will fetch meta data that you have defined in the pages.

```
    echo $this->Html->meta(
        'keywords',
        'enter any meta keyword here'
    );
    // Output
    <meta name="keywords" content="enter any meta keyword here" />

    echo $this->Html->meta(
        'description',
        'enter any meta description here'
    );
    // Output
    <meta name="description" content="enter any meta description here" />`
```

`echo $this->fetch('content');`

Will render the content that is defined in the view files.